# jQuery hover on image/div sliding down login box example transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change the hover js transition effect to an another transition (fadein, fadeout, simple transitions) etc.?!

http://jsfiddle.net/xjLVE/

HTML

```
<img id="login-trigger" src="http://www.jointcommission.org/assets/1/6/button-login.jpg" />
<div id="login-box">
    <p>Login now:</p>
    Username : <input />
    <br />
    Password : <input />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#login-trigger, #login-box').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'login-trigger') $('#login-box').slideDown('slow');
        clearTimeout( $('#login-box').data('timer') );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#login-box').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#login-box').slideUp('slow')
            }, 300)
        );
    }
});
```

Do you have an idea? Any solution?
TY

Comment: Did you try just replacing `slideDown` with `fadeIn` etc

Comment: Ty, and how can u add a custom delay? For example 1500 instead of slow  maybe or 100-200 instead of fast

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your `.slideDown` and `.slideUp` with the same (and opposite) responses:

http://jsfiddle.net/xjLVE/18/

```
$('#login-trigger, #login-box').on({mouseenter: function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'login-trigger') 
        $('#login-box').fadeIn('slow'); //Changed to fadeIn
        clearTimeout( $('#login-box').data('timer') );
}, mouseleave: function() {
    $('#login-box').data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
            $('#login-box').fadeOut('slow')  //Changed to fadeOut
    }, 300));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different jQuery animation like `.fadeOut()`

```
 $('#login-trigger, #login-box').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'login-trigger') $('#login-box').slideDown('slow');
        clearTimeout( $('#login-box').data('timer') );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#login-box').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#login-box').fadeOut('slow')
            }, 300)
        );
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H8TaV/

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$('#login-trigger, #login-box').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'login-trigger') $('#login-box').slideDown('slow');
        clearTimeout( $('#login-box').data('timer') );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#login-box').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $( "#login-box" ).animate({
                                        opacity: 0.15,
                                        left: "+=50",
                                        height: "toggle"
                                      }, 5000, function() {
                                        // Animation complete.
                                          $('#login-box').slideUp('slow')
                                      });

            }, 300)
        );
    }
});
```